# Savon: Adding an encoding to the body tag

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

How can I add an encoding attribute to the body tag using Savon?

Some background:
I am trying to use savon to connect to a SOAP resource. I can get the WSDL file and browse through the methods.

```
@client = Savon::Client.new("http://some.domain.com/v2messaging/service?WSDL")
```

when I try to use the login method

```
response = @client.request :service, :login do
  soap.body = { 
    "String_1" => "username",
    "String_2" => "password"
  }
end
```

I get this error:

*Failure/Error: response = @client.request :service, :login do Savon::SOAP::Fault: (env:Client) caught exception while handling request: unexpected encoding style: expected=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, actual*

The difference in the body tag.  Here is the expected xml (found through SOAPUI application):

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:service="etapestryAPI/service">
   <env:header/>
   <env:body>
      <service:login env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <String_1>username</String_1>
        <String_2>password</String_2>
      </service:login>
   </env:body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Savon sends:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:service="etapestryAPI/service" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ins0="http://java.sun.com/jax-rpc-ri/internal" xmlns:ins1="etapestryAPI/service">
    <env:Body>
        <service:login>
            <String_1>username</String_1>
            <String_2>password</String_2>
        </service:login>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

There are a few difference between these, but the error returned has to do with the env:encodingStyle attribute on the env:login tag.  How can add this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this one out.  To add an attribute to the function tag (in this case login), you can  pass in an additional parameter to the method:

```
response = @client.request :service, :login, "env:encodingStyle" => "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" do
  soap.body = { 
           "String_1" => "username",
           "String_2" => "password"
         }
end
```

This will probably now work without passing the block.